# Java. Scanner requests an additional line but does not print it

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

just entered this community and this is my first question here, so please bear with a noob. I created two classes, first is Student, a basic one with fields, constructor and getters. The second one has the main method, a LinkedList, a multiple-entry Scanner (for...) and two simple methods.
My problem is that despite the fact that the For loop has maximum index 1 (x = 0; x < 2), the Scanner expects a third row input and an enter but does not print the third line. I add the two classes, maybe I made a mistake and I would appreciate your help. Thank you in advance.

```
public class Student {

private String name;
private String surname;
private int firstMark;
private int secondMark;
private int finalExamMark;

public Student(String name, String surname, int firstMark, int secondMark, int finalExamMark) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.firstMark = firstMark;
    this.secondMark = secondMark;
    this.finalExamMark = finalExamMark;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public int getFirstMark() {
    return firstMark;
}

public int getSecondMark() {
    return secondMark;
}

public int getFinalExamMark() {
    return finalExamMark;
}

@Override
public String toString (){
    return this.name + " " + this.surname + " got " + this.firstMark + " at English, " + this.secondMark + " at Math and " + this.finalExamMark + " at the final exam.";
}
```

}

---

```
public class StudentMain {
static LinkedList<Student> courseAttend = new LinkedList<>();
static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    addStudent();
    printList(courseAttend);
}

private static void addStudent()  {
    for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
        String s1 = scanner.nextLine();
            String[] split = s1.split("\\s");
            courseAttend.add(new Student(split[0], split[1], Integer.parseInt(split[2]), Integer.parseInt(split[3]), Integer.parseInt(split[4])));
            scanner.nextLine();
    }
    scanner.close();
    }

private static void printList(LinkedList<Student> lista) {
    for (Student elem : lista) {
        System.out.println(elem);
    }
}
```

}

---

For example, if I input (without quotes)
"Young John 9 9 9"
"Johnson Anne 8 8 8" and I press enter, the cursor moves to next line and waits another input. Only after that third line and the final enter, the message is displayed but the third line is not shown.

Comment: scanner.nextLine(); doesn't print, it accepts input. you don't store the input anywhere on your last nextLine() call, so how do you expect it to be printed

Comment: As a matter of fact, I don't want the third line to be printed, only the first two. But I don't know how to make the Scanner close immediately after typing the first two rows. I would really appreciate if you could point me how to solve it, as I tried many variants without luck

Comment: who says you "have to" close the scanner? point is, in your loop you have two calls to your nextLine() but you ignore the information of the second call. why do you have to input a certain amount? because of this: for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) Do you understand the code you posted?

Comment: Why did you put ```scanner.nextLine();``` twice in the addStudent() for loop?

Comment: I tried without the second scanner.nextLine(); but it throws an exception, ArrayOutOfBounds, Index 1 is out of bounds. So next step would be to skip the second call to nextline() and to look for the mistake  somewhere at the array level.

Comment: I removed the second ```scanner.nextLine();``` then I've launched the problem passing *Young John 9 9 9*, pressed enter, *Johnson Anne 8 8 8*, pressed enter and it works fine

Comment: Thank you. This is most intriguing.       Using IntelliJ, I get "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1  at Verificari.StudentMain.addStudent(Verificari1.java:19)
 at Verificari.StudentMain.main(Verificari1.java:11)"         Using another IDE, BlueJ (for noobs), the program compiles and runs as expected.  I have to dig deeper, but now I am very glad that the code is ok.    Thank you both for your answers.

Comment: When a User has to enter multiple arguments (delimited with anything) for any given prompt, you can expect to have typos. Your prompt expects the User to enter 5 arguments on a single line delimited with a whitespace. What if the user accidentally hits the space bar twice or didn't hit it hard enough for one of the arguments? Your array won't have the length you think it does. Use `split("\\s+")` to take care of over-spacing, and check the split array length for the other problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. courseAttend should be a `List<Student> courseAttend = new ...List<>();` like your methode argument `printList(List<Student> students)` because both could be also a ArrayList and it is the normal way to in implement variables if they have not to be sepciefied, like in your case.
2. The loop has two nextLine() but you ignore the second one so you are creating a student and waiting of the next input and not saving the input
3. When a User has to enter multiple arguments for any given prompt, you can expect to have typos. Your prompt expects the User to enter 5 arguments and they are not even from the same typ on a single line delimited with a whitespace. What if the user accidentally give you an ivalid input like a integer as name or a String as mark.

   ```
   public class StudentMain {
       static List<Student> courseAttend = new LinkedList<>();
       static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
               courseAttend.add(createStudent());
           }
           scanner.close();
           printList(courseAttend);
       }

       private static Student createStudent(){
           System.out.print("name: ");
           String name = scanner.nextLine();
           System.out.print("surname: ");
           String surname = scanner.nextLine();
           System.out.print("first mark: ");
           int firstMark = scanner.nextInt();
           System.out.print("second mark: ");
           int secondMark = scanner.nextInt();
           System.out.print("final exam mark: ");
           int finalExamMark = scanner.nextInt();

           return new Student(name, surname, firstMark, secondMark ,finalExamMark);
        }

        private static void printList(List<Student> students) {
            for (Student elem : students) {
                System.out.println(elem);
            }
        }
   }
   ```

Comment: And yet, after the first iteration of the loop is finished, the scanner skips name and jumps to surname. It  shows "name: surname:   " connected, with no way to input for name, only after surname

Comment: The solution was to add       
        scanner.nextLine();        after      int finalExamMark = scanner.nextInt();